# How to create databases dynamically and instantiate JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am accepting database name from end-user and then I need to create and connect to the database dynamically using Spring `JdbcTemplate` so further I can execute DDL/DML statements within that database, so later on whenever user log-in to the system I will need to connect to the same database.

I have multiple end-users and need to connect them with their respective databases after they log in to the system.

Comment: If you want to create database during startup you can use Spring @Repository annotation. You can also use `application.properties` as storage for all your database parameters like credentials, collection names etc.

Comment: I dont have list of databases, I will accpet the name of database from my applicatoin from end user dynamically and then I need to create that database

Comment: My application is some sort of Web-based SQL Editor (like pgAdmin from postgresql, SQL developer from Oracle).

Comment: You can take `AbstractRoutingDataSource` as [explained here](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) as a starting point for dynamic data source switching.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Answer,

Following code snippet worked for me.

```
// create final Map
private final Map<Long, JdbcTemplate> datasourceFactory = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// put JdbcTemplate to the Map
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
Properties p = new Properties();
config.setDataSourceProperties(p);
config.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);
HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource(config);
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(hds);
datasourceFactory.put(someUniqueId, jdbcTemplate);
```

Access JdbcTemplate using below code snippet,

```
// Fetch the JdbcTemplate from the Map object
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = datasourceFactory.get(someUniqueId);
```

So In this way we can manage multiple datasources for a single Spring application.